Excel Column Width is Incorrect after first 2 columns - Created by c# OpenXML
I got a weird one and I've been searching online and can't seem to find anything like this. btw I'm new to OpenXML.
I just want to set the width of the first 10 columns of a sheet. Really simple. The first two column widths set fine. The ones after that are not the values I have in the code. But they do offset as I change the values, so I'm not sure how it's coming up with the values it is. For example, I set a column width to 18.43 and it comes out to 17.71. If I set it to 8.83 it goes down to 7.71.
Can anyone explain what is going on?
 WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
            Columns rMtlCols = new Columns();
            Column column1 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)1U, Max = (UInt32Value)1U, Width = 16.57, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column2 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)2U, Max = (UInt32Value)2U, Width = 32.86, CustomWidth = true };
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Column column3 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Column() 
                                                                                { Min = (UInt32Value)3U, 
                                                                                  Max = (UInt32Value)3U, 
                                                                                  Width = 18.43, 
                                                                                  CustomWidth = true 
                                                                                };
            Column column4 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)4U, Max = (UInt32Value)4U, Width = 8.43, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column5 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)5U, Max = (UInt32Value)5U, Width = 8.43, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column6 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)6U, Max = (UInt32Value)6U, Width = 6.86, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column7 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)7U, Max = (UInt32Value)7U, Width = 6.86, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column8 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)8U, Max = (UInt32Value)8U, Width = 9.43, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column9 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)9U, Max = (UInt32Value)9U, Width = 5.14, CustomWidth = true };
            Column column10 = new Column() { Min = (UInt32Value)10U, Max = (UInt32Value)10U, Width = 10.00, CustomWidth = true };
            rMtlCols.Append(column1);
            rMtlCols.Append(column2);
            rMtlCols.Append(column3);
            rMtlCols.Append(column4);
            rMtlCols.Append(column5);
            rMtlCols.Append(column6);
            rMtlCols.Append(column7);
            rMtlCols.Append(column8);
            rMtlCols.Append(column9);
            rMtlCols.Append(column10);

            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

 Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = document.WorkbookPart.
                GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "Raw Materials"
            };

sheets.Append(sheet);
            var sheetdata = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(rMtlCols, sheetdata);

I've tried various ways of adding the columns to the worksheet but I get the same result.

Create the workbook (and worksheet) as desired in Excel. Then download/install the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool and use it to view the .xlsx file. This will help you to see what you need.

Ok, so I did that and for a column width of 30, this is what I got. This is strange. I guess, I can copy this value, but it would be nice to know how it calculates the width.
Columns columns1 = new Columns();
Column column1 = new Column(){ Min = (UInt32Value)1U, Max = (UInt32Value)1U, Width = 30.7109375D, CustomWidth = true };

The following may be of interest: Welcome to the Open XML SDK for Office
